# Slim Framework Routing with asset files (eg. css files) not rendered

Tags: css, routes, slim

I am having this problem of rendering a view for this route on Slim Framework:

Here is my application directory structure:

```
|--project
    |--public
       |--assets
            |--css
                |--main.css
       |--index.php
       |--.htaccess
    |--app
        |--asset
            |--route.php
        |--controllers
            |--HomeController
            |--AuthController
        |--models
        |--views
            |--auth
                |--signup.php
            |--home
                |--index.php
        |--bootstrap.php
```

With the route:

```
$app->get('/[{home}]', 'app\controllers\HomeController:index')->setName('home');
```

everything works fine with the all assets files (in the css folder of the public folder) included and the uri for the css file is

```
http://localhost:8081/slim-auth/public/assets/css/main.css
```

But with the route:

```
$app->get('/auth/signup', 'app\controllers\AuthController:getSignUp')->setName('auth.signup');
```

There is  404 error accessing the css file where the browser tries to access the css file via the uri:

```
http://localhost:8081/slim-auth/public/auth/assets/css/main.css
```

instead of:

```
http://localhost:8081/slim-auth/public/assets/css/main.css
```

although the content of the requested route was displayed, the css was not rendered with the 404 response status

After changing the route to:

```
$app->get('/signup', 'app\controllers\AuthController:getSignUp')->setName('auth.signup');
```

Everything seems to work fine like the case of the home route.

Please is there anyway I could go around this? I'll really appreciate if this could be solved asap.

Comment: Could you show us the code where you include the css file to your html file?

Comment: @jmattheis: Yes, it is in a header.php file which is in a template folder, a child of the view folder (forgot to add it in the directory structure above). Here is the code in the header.php file

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">`

Comment: That is how relative paths work. Fastest fix is to use absolute path ie. `/assets/css/main.css`.

Comment: @Mika:  Thank you, I really appreciate this